# tableView.selectRow(...) doesn't work when I use UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

In my app I use `.present(...)` to show one View Controller on top of the other (these are the same VC). When I dismiss it (pull down from screen) I want to select some row in my first VC. For it I use UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate in which I have `print(...)` and `tableView.selectRow(...)` function. Print works fine, but tableView.selectRow doesn't work. What could be the issue?

```
extension UIViewController {
class func loadFromStoryboard<T: UIViewController>() -> T {
    let name = String(describing: T.self)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: name, bundle: nil)
    
    if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? T {
        return viewController
    } else {
        fatalError("Error: No initial view controller in \(name) stroryboard")
    }
  }
}

class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {
   let firstVC: FirstVC = FirstVC.loadFromStoryboard()
   ...
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadViewControllers()
   }

   private func generateViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController, image: UIImage?, title: String) -> UIViewController {
      let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
      ...
      return navigationVC
   }

   private func loadViewControllers() {
    viewControllers = [
        generateViewController(rootViewController: firstVC, image: ..., title: "...")
    ]
   }
   ...
   private func openVC() {
      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "FirstVC", bundle: nil)
      let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "FirstVC") as! FirstVC
      vc.presentationController?.delegate = vc
      self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ...
}


//FirstVC
extension FirstVC: UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {
    func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
        print("VC was dismissed")
        self.tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
    }
}
```

In the console I see "VC was dismissed", but row doesn't select.

P.S. I use Xcode 12.2 and iOS 14.2.
The `tableView` is an IBOutlet, if it's important.

Answer (score 1):

You should set:

```
vc.presentationController?.delegate = self
```

Instead of:

```
vc.presentationController?.delegate = vc
```

Because you lose delegate as soon as you dismiss vc. You should listen dismissal of FirstVC on self where you present FirstVC.

If you just miss that it's ok. But if you can't understand why I can share more details :)

Comment: Thx for you answer, but I can't setup UITabBarController as delegate. I call openVC() func in my tabBarController

Comment: It's the logic of the delegate. Can you add more code of your classes? Where are you call presentationControllerDidDismiss from? And what is inside of your tabbarcontroller?

Comment: Your `self` inside `self.tableView.selectRow` is refers to dismissed `FirstVC` are you aware of this?

Comment: I'm not calling presentationControllerDidDismiss from anywhere, this method is associated with UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate, it works on its own.

Comment: My project is very large, I can't show everything that is in the classes.
I'll try to explain once again what I'm doing: I have a TabBarController, which has two tabs. I also have a View that appears on top of the TabBarController and other ViewControllers. What do I want to do? For example, I'm on the first tab (FirstVC), then I open my View, there is a button on it, I click on it and the FirstVC presents (I open a new copy of it), then when I dismiss this FirstVC and I want to be able to update the information in the FirstVC (in the TabBarController). I hope I haven't confused you.

Comment: No, it's OK. I mean that: you have two instances of FirstVC one is `tabBarChildFirstVC` and other is `presentedFirstVC` so you should set: `presentedFirstVC.presentationController?.delegate = tabBarChildFirstVC`

Comment: In this case I catch Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: tableView

Comment: I added the code how I add ViewControllers to my TabBarController in the question. Perhaps it'll helps you understand what the issue is.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint to the line after the print statement and check why self.tableView is nil. I think your FirstVC should have a tableView in there so it's a new problem and we can figure it now.

Comment: I put breakpoint and see that self = MusicPlayer.FirstVC 0x0000000109e0ec80, and tableView = (UITableView?) nil. Perhaps I'm not using the UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224587/discussion-between-ibrahimyilmaz-and-vyacheslavbakinkskiy).